# Append an object instead of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery I am using a `for loop` to append `div`'s with some variables, but it is appending the string instead of an object. How do I output an object?

For example:

```
row.append('<div data-pos="' + i + '">' + text + '</div>');
```

I have also tried the longer way which works on new browsers, but fails at the append line without an error on an older ipad running chrome and safari.

eg.

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
x.setAttribute('data-pos', i);
row.append(x);
x.append(text);
```

Comment: What is `i` here and what is `text` here. Give an example.

Comment: Your existing code works for me. `const i = 3;
const text = 'foo'` plus your code results in `<div data-pos="3">foo</div>` in the HTML markup

Comment: `+` works only on strings and numbers. Anything else will get converted to one or the other. You can't meaningfully stitch together a string and a `HTMLElement`. Either use HTML source, or use `HTMLElement` objects; you cannot insert the latter into a former.

Comment: If you have an unknown error, open up a debugger and make it known — debugging blind is not fun. You can use Weinre, or Safari remote development tools, vorlon.js... Many options.

Comment: @Amadan By unknown error, I mean there is no error, it just stops working at the append line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insertAdjacentHTML(), it parses the specified text as HTML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position

```
row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div data-pos=${i}>${text}</div>`);
```